# How to make parent li class stays even if you click child li?

Tags: jquery

```
$("li a").filter(function () {
    return this.href == location.href.replace(/#.*/, "");
}).parent().addClass("selected");
```

Hi, I have a menu with one level submenus and I am using the above code to add class to the current link I visited. The outcome is this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="selected"><a href="link1.php">Link1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="link1.php?id=aaa">SubLink1</a></li>
            <li><a href="link1.php?id=bbb">SubLink2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="link2.php">Link2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="link2.php?id=aaa">SubLink1</a></li>
            <li><a href="link2.php?id=bbb">SubLink2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, if I click any of the submenu link, the "selected" class is gone and added to the submenu link I clicked.

Is there a way to make the "selected" class stays on the parent li even if I click a submenu link?

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Update: None of the given answers work so far but I am trying to figure it out based on the given answers. But looks like I am about to give up :(

Comment: you want "selected" class to be there for the `li` which is having anchor tag ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine. If you remove the filtering and just use `$(this)` in the click-handler for the `a`-elements it should work.

```
$('a').on('click',function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Lovkawcz/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').on('click',function() {
$(this).parent('li').addClass("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add a class to your `li` elements which you want add the `selected` class and then change the jQuery selector in your script.

```
<script>

$("li.first-level-menu a").filter(function () {
    return this.href == location.href.replace(/#.*/, "");
}).parent().addClass("selected");

</script>
<ul>
    <li class="first-level-menu selected"><a href="#">Link1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">SubLink1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SubLink2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

> EDIT

In any case you must have something that allows you to recognize the elements that you want, so you can create a class ans use it as marker for your purpose or you have to use the HTML structure as already mentioned.

Another, and probably last, way to do it:

```
<script>

$("ul.main-menu > li a").filter(function () {
    return this.href == location.href.replace(/#.*/, "");
}).parent().addClass("selected");

</script>
<ul class="main-menu">
    <li class="selected"><a href="#">Link1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">SubLink1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SubLink2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I am trying to highlight the current page and I only need one class for every parent li.

Comment: also I have at least 5 parent li.

Answer (score 0):

The Marco Mercury answer will work fine, but if you want to do it in jQuery without changing the html, you can try with this snippet:

```
$('li a').not('ul > li > ul > li a').on('click',function() {
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
});
```

it will match the `li a` and exlude the childs with the `not`.

the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrdm3rjz/)

Comment: Hi sir, thanks for ur reply. It probably will work but not with pages with different url. I am using this as my main navigation menu.